# Recursive make: correct way to insert `$(MAKEFLAGS)`

Tags: makefile

How can I use `$(MAKEFLAGS)` (or another way of passing variables defined on the command line to sub-make) in a way that supports invocation from shell with both `make VAR=val` and `make -args`?

I need my subprojects configurable, but I hate autotools, so I'm using make variables for this, e.g. invoking from shell:

```
$ make USE_SSE3=1
```

and `USE_SSE3` needs to apply to all builds in all sub-makefiles.

[The manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html) states that:

> if you do ‘make -ks’ then MAKEFLAGS gets the value ‘ks’.

Therefore I'm using `-$(MAKEFLAGS)` (with a dash prefix) in my Makefile.

However, that **expands into invalid arguments when variables with no flags are used**. If I run:

```
$ make FOO=bar
```

then sub-make gets invalid `-FOO=bar`. OTOH without the dash prefix variable definitions work, then but `make -s`, etc. don't.

Is there a syntax/variable/hack that makes passing of arguments *and* lone variable definitions work with sub-makefiles?

The legacy `$(MKFLAGS)` doesn't have the weird dash prefix problem, but it doesn't include variable definitions either. I've tried fixing the variable with `$(patsubst)`, but that only made things worse by trimming whitespace.

I need the solution to be compatible with the outdated GNU Make 3.81 shipped with Mac OS X Mavericks.

---

```
foo:
    $(MAKE) -C subproject -$(MAKEFLAGS)
```

---

```
$ make foo -s       # MAKEFLAGS = 's'
$ make foo BAR=baz  # MAKEFLAGS = 'BAR=baz'
$ make foo -j8      # MAKEFLAGS = ' --job-server=…'
```

Comment: This seems to work without any special effort. Try `foo: $(MAKE) bar` and `bar: echo flags are $(MAKEFLAGS), BAR is $(BAR)`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You shouldn't set `MAKEFLAGS` at all.  Why do you want to?  You didn't give any reason to do so.

`MAKEFLAGS` is intended, really, to be an internal implementation passing arguments from a parent make to a child make.  It's not intended, generally, to be modified by a makefile.  About the only thing you can usefully do to it is add new flags.

If you just run the recursive make using the `$(MAKE)` variable rather than hardcoding `make`, it will Just Work:

```
recurse:
        @$(MAKE) all FOO=bar
```

or whatever.

Comment: I don't need to modify `MAKEFLAGS`, I just want them to *work*. Your example loses variables that were passed to top-level make. I need to allow user to set configuration variables and sub-makefiles to react to them.

Comment: No it doesn't.  All variables that were passed to the top level ARE passed, as command-line variables, to sub-makes--as long as you don't mess around with MAKEFLAGS.  Please show an example that does not work, because people have been successfully using this for 20+ years.

Comment: Oh, I see — flags are passed implicitly to sub-makefiles. I wrongly assumed the variable has to be used explicitly.

Comment: I upvoted this answer, because it's right, but I'm going to add a comment because the answer wasn't clear to me initially. The short version is: Do not use $(MAKEFLAGS) in a rule; if you use $(MAKE) in a rule, make will ensure that $(MAKEFLAGS) gets picked up by the sub-make...magically...and everything Just Works.

Comment: If you want to pass things explicitly you can also use `export`.

Comment: The "[MAKEFLAGS] it's not intended ... to be modified by a makefile" part needs to be *heavily* qualified, particularly given how unclear the Make manual is in this regard. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31789730/1235165

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of "heavy qualification" you had in mind.  I do say _about the only thing you can usefully do to it is add new flags_.

Answer (score 4):

Years too late I got your answer if I got it right.
You can construct `$(MAKEARGS)` manually yourself like:

```
MAKEARGS := $(strip \
  $(foreach v,$(.VARIABLES),\
    $(if $(filter command\ line,$(origin $(v))),\
      $(v)=$(value $(v)) ,)))
```

`MAKEARGS :=` assign static

`strip` cleans leading and trailing whitespaces.

`foreach v` iterate over all variable names.

`origin $(v)` check if variable origin is "command line".

`$(v)=$(value $(v))`  output env assignment string.

Alternatively you can unpick the `$(MAKEFLAGS)` like:

```
MAKEARGS := $(wordlist 2,$(words $(MAKEFLAGS)),$(MAKEFLAGS))
MAKEFLAGS := $(firstword $(MAKEFLAGS))
```

Which can leave you with cleaner code for further recursions IMHO. I say this because I sometimes need to keep apart arguments and flags in certain cases. Especially as you get caught in debugging a recursion djungle.
But for any specific case one should consult [the manual about recursive options processing.](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html)

Changing the `$(MAKEFLAGS)` can lead to unwanted malfunction.

Another useful information for the willing user could be that the `$(MAKEFLAGS)` variable is basically the whole argument list passed to make, not only the flag characters. So `$(info MAKEFLAGS = $(MAKEFLAGS))` can give you something like:

```
MAKEFLAGS = rRw -- VAR=val
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

To check if -B is present in make flags i do :

```
BB_CLOBBER := $(shell echo $(MAKEFLAGS) | grep wB)
ifeq (,$(BB_CLOBBER))
  # also force clobber make if these files are missing
  BB_CLOBBER := $(shell (test -e $(bb_gen)/minimal/.config && test -e $(bb_gen)/full/.config) || echo "B")
endif

bb_prepare:
ifneq (,$(BB_CLOBBER))
    @rm -rf $(bb_gen)/full
    ...
```